# Docker container to change default DNS server

Tags: docker, dnsmasq

I am learning to work with Docker containers and I trying what I thought would be a simple exercise, but running into issues.  I want to use a container to change the default DNS server that my machine uses.
So when I say

```
>>  host facebook.com
```

the result should be the same as

```
>> host facebook.com _myserverIP_
```

So I looked around and found several images on Docker hub and based on those made this very simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add dnsmasq 
COPY dnsmasq.conf /etc/dsnmasq.conf
EXPOSE 53/tcp 53/udp
VOLUME ["/etc/dnsmasq"]
CMD ["dnsmasq"]
```

in dnsmasq.conf, I put:

```
log-queries
no-resolv
server= _myserverIP_
```

I build and run:

```
docker build -t dns .
docker run --name dns3 -d -p 53:53/udp --cap-add=NET_ADMIN dns
```

this gives me `2c3f046593c5d6e664d202e78d92172c75f71b95c45a9ea307af49bd1e2d5125`

but when I try to see what containers are running, I see that this container isn't even running, so I can't do the next step of checking if it is working.

I am clearly missing something basic, but can't figure out what.

Comment: What's the output of `docker ps -a` ?

Comment: post the output of `docker logs dns3`

Comment: Output of `docker ps -a`
`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
5e729e49ca53        dns                 "dnsmasq"           4 seconds ago       Exited (0) 3 seconds ago                       dns3`

Comment: For `docker logs dns3` I there is no output.

Comment: Try `docker run` without `-d` to see what's happening. i.e. `docker run --name dns3  -p 53:53/udp --cap-add=NET_ADMIN dns`

Comment: Tried without the `-d`.  Still not seeing any containers running. 

It sounds like the container runs and then exits because it has nothing to do.  Do I need to use some command to make it keep dnsmasq running?

Answer (score 1):

Your system will look in `/etc/resolv.conf` to determine what dns servers to use. Use this guide to determine how dnsmasq uses `/etc/resolv.conf` https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/dnsmasq

I suspect you will need to mount resolv.conf as well.

Comment: ok, I added a resolv.conf and put `nameserver _myserverIP` and I put `COPY resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` in the Dockerfile.  But nothing seems to change.  

Can you please tell me understand the why/how of mounting resolv.conf?  I am very much a newbie!